# Asp.Net Core 1.1 consume web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing a web application using asp.net core 1.1 with VisualStudio 2017 Community, in this application i consume a web-api service with this:

```
public static T SendPostRequest<T>(string pController, T pParam){
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()){
    string uri = API_URL + pController;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var jsonInString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((T)pParam);
    var content = new StringContent(jsonInString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

}

When this code arrive to api controller my object is null, but jsonInString has the values of my object.
The same error pass when I use PostMan, using raw and JSON(applications/json), if you see the properties of my object are nulls

[image]

But if i use postman with form-data, in my apicontroller i recive the data properties of my object, I need your help how i can receive values of my object when I send from the code in my asp.net core web, I hope your help

[image]

Comment: Change `FromForm` -> `FromBody`

Comment: Yup! Just Change FromForm to FromBody

Answer (score 0):

to be able to deal correctly, the data that arrives at the web controllers api net.core 1.1, I recommend you use what I indicate below.

METHOD to CONTROLLER

```
    [Route("GetAll")]
    [HttpPost]
     ...here your security directives
       **example**
    [AllowAnonymous]
     public JsonResult GetAll([FromBody]MupdateDto data)
    {
       try
        {
          List<MupdateDto > result = Service.GetAll(data);       

            return Json(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            response.GenerateResponse(TransData.ResponseKo(ex.Message, -69), null, null);
            throw;
        }


    }
```

It can be seen that in the sets, the call path **[Route("GetAll")]** is indicated and the type of parameter to be received **[FromBody]**.
example structure

```
  public class MupdateDto
{

    /// <summary>
    /// data
    /// </summary>
    public string data{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Update { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Lparam
    /// </summary>
    public long  Lparam { get; set; }


}
```

Now with your server up, make the call from postman with the following considerations

**-choose the type marked in the decoration of the method**

[image]

**-now is the time to prepare the data, instead of passing them as type form, as indicated above, I advise you to pass them as RAW, as I show below**
[image]

can you determine what type of data I'm sending is typo JSON 
[image]

**just one more thing, keep in mind that the data filled in RAW is of the type that the model waits on the server, if you have a property of type long and the value filled in that RAW property is string, its object it will reach null.**

I hope you have explained me correctly and this will help you.
a greeting